# Join on Hive on different keyspace tables on DSE

Tags: hive, hiveql, datastax-enterprise

Is this possible to run JOIN query on DSE Hive with different keypsaces tables in Cassandra ?

I'm trying to execute below query with no success

```
hive> select * from mykeyspace1.table1 a JOIN keyspace_185.table_508 b on a.companyid=b.companyid limit 10;
```

there are two KEYSPACES mykeyspace1 and keyspace_508.
In my case map reduce run with no error but not showing any result.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me for a simple test. select a.name, b.state from test7.test1 a join test8.test1 b on  a.name = b.name; Maybe something wrong with the data or join condition.